Word Heading Styles Keep Resetting Paragraph Spacing
I made a Word template which works great, everything works perfectly apart from the Headings which if you reset styles/template ends up back with a -1.3cm paragraph spacing.
I fixed everything manually, created a new normal.dotm.
Deleted the old one, then replaced with the new one...
lo and behold... the -1.3cm issue is back again!

Anyone have any ideas on how to make the manual changes permanent? Ideally I want to create a new 'normal.dotm' that others can just copy to their machine to make their life easier. All of the other styles are fine, the colours are fine... it's just this one issue that keeps resetting.
When looking through the styles xml there doesn't seem to be any specifics relating to paragraph spacing...

If these are numbered paragraphs, you can't reset the indent in the styles or paragraph dialogs. It has to be reset in the numbering dialog. http://wordfaqs.ssbarnhill.com/NumberAlignment2007.htm

Hi, this is a programming forum, not a Word forum. Your question is off-topic here and likely will be closed without answers. The confusion is understandable. https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic  This would be an appropriate question on the Microsoft Community https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word  or on Super User https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-word or other forums. If you do post something there, you should delete this question or at least add a link in your question here to the new question there to help others.

Thanks, I did have a look there but could not find any way to adjust, even tried unpacking the xmls to see if I could find, edit, and save the spacing changes but was unable to find the data.
Thankfully I have been able to resolve it using a button I didn't know the true function of within the design tab.

I was able to fix this issue by going to Design > Set as Default after making my adjustments, this then overwrote the original template and so far whenever I reset or copy it seems to work ok.
